# Chrome console is not working, showing undefined values

Tags: angular, typescript

In Chrome console is values are showing undefined while on sources values are showing.

[image]

Here i am getting values of this.listdealfunding but on console it is showing undefined.

[image]

Comment: That's because the context of `this` will not be your class, it's probably `window`

Comment: It's very strange, it should work. I do not agree with the comment above. Could you show the code of `getDealFunding` function? It's hard to see it in the picture

Comment: Do you try accessing it while stopped on a breakpoint?

Comment: yes i tried to access on console on breakpoint also.but same is coming.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The browser won't have access to the `this` context in your class *UNLESS* you're stopped on a break point in that class.

Comment: He stopped at a breakpoint, the context should therefore be correct

Comment: No, don't know if it's an official browser bug or not, but the context won't be correct for the console, breakpoint or not. So this answer is/was actually correct the first time around.

Comment: @bug-a-lot - just tested in an Angular app and the console was able to access a class's property on a breakpoint

Comment: But was the context within a lambda? Because you need something that creates a closure in order for this behavior to exhibit. And then, it's also important to note what the ES version you are targeting on compilation.